# MDX filter one dimension by multiple criteria using "like"

Tags: filter, where-clause, mdx, having

I'm new on MDX, and please help me with an example of how can I build an MDX query that will have a filter equivalent with the following SQL:

select *

from [dbo].[FactPurchase]

where Artikelnummer like 'E75%'

or Artikelnummer like 'S241%%NA'

or Artikelnummer like 'S241%%SW'

or Artikelnummer like 'S241%%PL'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer that works for my needs here:
http://sqljason.com/2010/04/searching-substrings-in-mdx.html